# QGIS Zonal Statistics (Variety) returns zero or keymap error depending on QGIS version

Tags: zonal-statistics, windows-8, qgis-3

I need to calculate Variety of pixels for every polygon in a shapefile but the analysis returns zero.

Polygons are much bigger than a raster cell which is 10 m. Polygons are completely covered with raster cells. Raster cells have 8 categories - from 1 to 8 (reclassified aspect). No Data from original aspect raster were converted to 0 (at least this was set in a reclassification dialog). Polygons, raster and project have the same coordinate system (EPSG 5514) and are stored on a disk, no temp layers. Polygons have valid geometry with no errors. Raster is a geoTIFF.

[image: raster and polygons]

I have searched all the questions with "Zonal stats returns zero or empty values", tried the solutions in there but with no luck. I have no idea what´s wrong.

The analysis doesn´t work for me in QGIS 3.10.4 LTR, the log says nothing wrong, it just doesn´t do what it should.
When I tried the same in QGIS 2.18 the analysis fails with a KeyError:

[image: KeyError]

Any tips?

Comment: Saving raster to different format (I tried ESRI hdr and geopackage) doesn´t solve it.

Comment: Saving polygon shapefile to different format (I tried geopackage) doesn´t solve it.

Comment: Converting polygons to wgs84, raster to wgs84 or both to wgs84 didn´t help.

Comment: I´d be happy if you tested it yourself in your QGIS versions... Zip with data is here: https://www.transfernow.net/RlrNmx042020

Comment: Have you made sure the polygons are valid? Try `Fix geometry`

Comment: Oh mama, fixing polygons in ArcGIS has solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing geometry in QGIS showed no issues as well as checking validity or all those fixing things in QGIS.
I had to Repair geometry in ArcGIS - polygons had several self-intersections that QGIS hadn´t recognized.
Zonal statistics with repaired polygons works well now.